# Sharing existing media folder with pods on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm working on my toy project and I want to share an existing folder with media files with pods running on Kubernetes (Docker Desktop's built in Kubernetes on Windows 10 or microk8s on my home linux server). What is the best way to do it? I have searched through the docs and there are no exemaples with existing folder and data.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to share the local folder to kubernetes pods? OR Do you want to share the folder among pods?

Comment: @DharaniDharGolladasari I want to share the local folder with existing data to kubernetes pods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file or directory from the filesystem of the host node is mounted into your Pod by a hostPath volume.You can create a PV with hostpath so that you can claim in the pod configurations. For this your existing directory has to be in the node where the pods are going to create.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: registry.k8s.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /data
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```

Only root has access to the newly created files and folders on the underlying hosts. To be able to write to a hostPath drive, you must either execute your process as root in a privileged Container or change the file permissions on the host.

For detailed information refer to this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)

**NOTE: Avoiding the usage of HostPath volumes whenever possible is a best practise since they pose numerous security issues.**